# Calculate age from birth date using NSDateComponents in Swift

Tags: swift, nsdatecomponents

I am trying calculate the age from birthdayDate in Swift with this function:

```
var calendar : NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

var dateComponentNow : NSDateComponents = calendar.components(
             NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear, 
             fromDate: birthday, 
             toDate: age, 
             options: 0)
```

But I get an error `Extra argument toDate in call`

In objective c this was the code, but I don't know why get this error:

```
NSDate* birthday = ...;

NSDate* now = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents* ageComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] 
                               components:NSYearCalendarUnit 
                               fromDate:birthday
                               toDate:now
                               options:0];
NSInteger age = [ageComponents year];
```

Is there correct form better than this?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You get an error message because `0` is not a valid value for `NSCalendarOptions`. 
For "no options", use `NSCalendarOptions(0)` or simply `nil`:

```
let ageComponents = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitYear,
                              fromDate: birthday,
                                toDate: now,
                               options: nil)
let age = ageComponents.year
```

(Specifying `nil` is possible because `NSCalendarOptions` conforms to the `RawOptionSetType` protocol which in turn inherits
from `NilLiteralConvertible`.)

**Update for Swift 2:**

```
let ageComponents = calendar.components(.Year,
    fromDate: birthday,
    toDate: now,
    options: [])
```

**Update for Swift 3:**

Assuming that the Swift 3 types `Date` and `Calendar` are used:

```
let now = Date()
let birthday: Date = ...
let calendar = Calendar.current

let ageComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year], from: birthday, to: now)
let age = ageComponents.year!
```

Comment: @NaveedKhan: Thank you for the edit suggestion. However, the Swift 3 code is correct as it stands if the new `Date` type is used instead of the "old" `NSDate`. Please let me know if there is any problem with it.

Comment: please run the command in the second last line of your code in swift 3... 
'calendar.datecomponen't is replaced by 'calendar.component'

Comment: @NaveedKhan: That is strange. I just double-checked that the  Swift 3 code compiles in Xcode 8.2.1 (Swift 3.0) and in Xcode 8.3 (Swift 3.1). Which Xcode version are you using? Did you try the exact code as posted above?

Answer (score 21):

I create this method its very easy just put the birthday date in the method and this will return the Age as a Int

#### Swift 3

```
func calcAge(birthday: String) -> Int {
    let dateFormater = DateFormatter()
    dateFormater.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
    let birthdayDate = dateFormater.date(from: birthday)
    let calendar: NSCalendar! = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: .gregorian)
    let now = Date()
    let calcAge = calendar.components(.year, from: birthdayDate!, to: now, options: [])
    let age = calcAge.year
    return age!
}
```

#### Swift 2

```
func calcAge(birthday: String) -> Int{
    let dateFormater = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormater.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
    let birthdayDate = dateFormater.dateFromString(birthday)
    let calendar: NSCalendar! = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
    let now: NSDate! = NSDate()
    let calcAge = calendar.components(.Year, fromDate: birthdayDate!, toDate: now, options: [])
    let age = calcAge.year
    return age
}
```

#### Usage

```
print(calcAge("06/29/1988"))
```

Comment: Hey thx for your code, it doesn't work on Swift 3.0 anymore. Can you maybe post an updated version? It helped me in my App.

Comment: @Dug, thank you for noticing the difference in `dateFormat`. Yet, you did not perfectly kept identical behavior between the two pieces of code, as you left `YYYY` for one and `yyyy` for the other. Quoting Apple: ["_It uses yyyy to specify the year component. A common mistake is to use YYYY. yyyy specifies the calendar year whereas YYYY specifies the year (of “Week of Year”), used in the ISO year-week calendar._"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1)

Comment: Thanks for the info, I had the wrong year format in my project as well

Answer (score 10):

For swift 4 works fine

```
func getAgeFromDOF(date: String) -> (Int,Int,Int) {

    let dateFormater = DateFormatter()
    dateFormater.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd"
    let dateOfBirth = dateFormater.date(from: date)

    let calender = Calendar.current

    let dateComponent = calender.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: 
    dateOfBirth!, to: Date())

    return (dateComponent.year!, dateComponent.month!, dateComponent.day!)
}

let age  = getAgeFromDOF(date: "2000-12-01")

print("\(age.0) Year, \(age.1) Month, \(age.2) Day")
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for Swift 3

```
let myDOB = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: 1994, month: 9, day: 10))!
let myAge = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month], from: myDOB, to: Date()).month!
let years = myAge / 12
let months = myAge % 12
print("Age : \(years).\(months)")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working in swift 3 for me..

```
let now = NSDate()
    let calendar : NSCalendar = NSCalendar.current as NSCalendar
    let ageComponents = calendar.components(.year, from: datePickerView.date, to: now as Date, options: [])
    let age = ageComponents.year!
    ageCalculated.text = String(age)
```

Thanks to @Martin R

Answer (score 1):

This is the best way on swift 5

```
lazy var dateFormatter : DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        return formatter
    }()

let birthday = dateFormatter.date(from: "1980-04-25")
let timeInterval = birthday?.timeIntervalSinceNow
let age = abs(Int(timeInterval! / 31556926.0))
```

Comment: Works fine for me in playground.  Just going to make a var and connect to a date picker and link it to where the date of birth is in the above code.   Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

//Create string extension to make more easy

```
extension String {
            func getDate(format: String) -> Date {
                let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
                dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
                return dateFormatter.date(from: self) ?? Date()
            } 
        }
```

1. Get today's date and your birthday date

`let today = Date()`

`let birthDate = "1990-01-01".getDate(format: "yyyy-MM-dd")`

2. Create an instance of the user's current calendar

`let calendar = Calendar.current`

3. Use calendar to get difference between two dates

`let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: birthDate, to: today)`

`let ageYears = components.year` //get how many years old

`let ageMonths = components.month` //extra months

`let ageDays = components.day` // extra days