# NSTimeInterval to Components

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdatecomponents, nstimeinterval

I'm trying to convert the Objective-C code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1386746/130427), with the correction found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14921943/130427), to Swift:

```
var theTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval()
var calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)

var date1 = NSDate()
var date2 = NSDate(timeInterval: theTimeInterval, sinceDate: date1)

var unitFlags = NSCalendarUnit(UInt.max)
var info = calendar.components(unitFlags, fromDate:date1, toDate:date2, options:0)
```

However, on the finial line, Xcode is giving me an inexplicable error:

**Extra argument 'toDate' in call**

I looked at the code for `NSCalendar` by command-clicking it and the function signature I'm using seems to exactly match its `components` method. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate age from birth date using NSDateComponents in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25232009/calculate-age-from-birth-date-using-nsdatecomponents-in-swift) - (Replace `options:0` by `options:nil`)

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is the correct implementation for Swift 4. Notes:

- In components use whatever you need
- Looks like the argument 'options' was removed (see [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar))

```swift
    var theTimeInterval = TimeInterval()
    var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)

    var date1 = Date()
    var date2 = Date(timeInterval: theTimeInterval, since: date1)

    //NSCalendarUnit from objc are Calendar.Component in swift
    var components: Set<Calendar.Component> = [.hour, .minute, .second]
    var info = calendar.dateComponents(components,
                                       from: date1, to: date2)
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
var info = calendar.components(unitFlags, fromDate: date1, toDate: date2, options: NSCalendarOptions(0))
```

You have to write the `NSCalentarOptions` enum.