# How To Get the Age In Difference Between TwoDays

Tags: swift, core-data

How to calculate the age in two days given date and current date,

Here i have paste the code i have written

please help me

```
 *var ageStr = ""
        var date2 = selecteddate
        formattedDateFromString(dateString: date2, withFormat: "MMM d,yyyy")
        let dateformetter = DateFormatter()

        //dateformetter.dateFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
        var dateStr = dateformetter.date(from: date2)
        let calender = Calendar.current
        let now = Date()


      guard dateStr == nil else{
          print("====ramjan--99089808=====",dateStr)
        return 0
      }
       let ageComponents = calender.dateComponents([.month,.day,.year],from: date as Date,to: now)
       print("====suresh====",ageComponents)
      if ageComponents.year != 0{
           ageStr = "Yrs."

          return ageComponents.year!
      }
     else if ageComponents.month == 1
        {
     ageStr = "Month"

            return ageComponents.month!    
    }
      else{
           ageStr = "day"

          return ageComponents.day!
      }
  return ageComponents.day!
}
```

Any Help will be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Compare for example [Calculate age from birth date using NSDateComponents in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25232009/calculate-age-from-birth-date-using-nsdatecomponents-in-swift).

Comment: @Kaushik: "Thanks" and similar phrases should be *removed,* not added.

Comment: You can find the difference between two dates and then extract the year component from it

Comment: Have you solved you problem?

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4**

```
let now = Date()
let birthDate: Date = Given Date..
let calendar = Calendar.current

let component = calendar.dateComponents([.year], from: birthDate, to: now)
let age = component.year!
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This code Swift 4

```
func findAgeFromBirthDate(_ birthDate:Date) ->Int {
        let now = Date();
        let calendar = Calendar.current;

        let ageComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year], from: birthDate, to: now);
        let age = ageComponents.year!;
//        print(age);
        return age;
    }
```